# OAuth access failed for brand account

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-oauth

OAuth sign in with scopes to get access to youtube fails when brand channel is chosen in consent screen. Works correctly with average main account's youtube channel.

```
scope: "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
config: {
  client_id: my_client_id,
  fetch_basic_profile: true,
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  response_type: 'permission',
  access_type: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent'
}
```

```
Request https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=issueToken&response_type=token%20id_token&login_hint=AJDLj6JUa8yxXrhHdWRHIV0S13cANzW1y8OtI22VrYqaEC2i73av3HLVph3WpN9U_HlWSNxCsiYTB2bXOl1-DWQmT0zrdSxGa1JR03gPm3hk1GCjY9-EQsDI5aEH73UEvOOCoqynaOnr&client_id={my_real_token_here}&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000&scope=openid%20profile%20email&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000

Failed with 403, response - { "error" : "invalid_request" }
```

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    .signIn({ ...config, scope })
    .then(res => {
      const token = res.getAuthResponse().access_token

      return token
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err) # {type: "tokenFailed", idpId: "google", error: "server_error"} 

      throw new Error()
    })
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?